# jasmine test javascript inner function

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here is my javascript code

```
function organization() {
  var self = this;

  function activate() {
    // statements
  }
}
```

I know the scope of the method activate() remains inside the method organization() and that is the challenge I am facing.

My requirement is to write a test in Jasmine to ensure method activate have been called.

```
    it('activate method defined?', function() {    
      expect(activate()).toBeDefined();
    });
```

but this test is failing with the message

> TypeError: activate is not a function

Any inputs to make the above test success will be highly helpful.

Comment: I think your best bet is to make `activate` public by defining it on `this` or on the prototype of `organization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check that private function 'activate' actually called or defined. You need to check that public function 'organization' as I understand is called or defined and if activate set some public properties etc. For example:

```
function organization() {
    var vm = this;
    activate();        
    function activate() {
        vm.activated = true;
    }
}

it('should activate organization', function() {
    organization();

    expect(vm.activated).toBe(true);
});
```

Or if you need, you can make function activate as public:

```
function organization() {
   var vm = this;
   vm.isActivated = false;
   vm.activate = activate;

   function activate() {
       vm.isActivated = true;
   }
}

it('should activate organization', function() {
    vm.activate();

    expect(vm.isActivated).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tried the second option and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Define the script in this way.

```
function organization() {
  var self = this;

  self.activate = function() {
    // statements
  }}
```

and access the functiion like this

```
var obj = new organization();

obj.activate();
```